# Determining Power Supply Requirements for an 8x4 Grid Display of Chained 32x64 Pixel LED Matrices

Tags: power-supply, power, current, raspberry-pi, led-matrix

I am planning to build an 8x4 grid display using chained 32x64 pixel LED matrices driven by a Raspberry Pi, and I've found mixed information online about the power supply required for such a setup. Could someone please help me determine the appropriate power supply specifications to ensure stable and reliable operation?

Here are some additional details:

- Each of the panels draws ~3.5 amps at full brightness. This is for an art installation, so I do not intend to be running all pixels at full brightness often (or ever?) but I wouldn't want to fry anything on accident
- The 8x4 grid display will consist of a total of 32 individual LED matrices broken into 3 separately driven chains
- I want to power the entire setup using a single power supply, including the Raspberry Pi, if feasible

The instructions in the renowned [hzeller/rpi-rgb-led-matrix](https://github.com/hzeller/rpi-rgb-led-matrix/blob/master/wiring.md#a-word-about-power) repo recommend 3.5A / panel, but 3.5 * 32 = 112A which seems like... a lot? Are power supplies of that size easily available to consumers / safe to use? Will that take out my apartment?

Any guidance would be much, much appreciated!

Comment: That link actually says 3.5A for a smaller panel then you're using. Can you link a datasheet for your panels?

Comment: Cabling for 112A is challenging. I would use several power supplies to get the current to less than 20 Amp per supply. Splitting the chains into six power groups will get the current to about 10 A each. Thes are much more avilable and easier to work with.

Comment: @user1850479 the panel I am using says up to 4A, [here's the link](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2277).

Comment: @RussellH interesting, this might be a silly question but would that require me to have 6 outlets?

Comment: See user1850479's answer @Jordan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manufacturer, they're 4A max, 2A for "typical" (not solid white patterns). For 32 panels that's been 64 and 128A depending on how much of the panel you expect to light up. Perhaps lower if you intended to only have sparse images on the panel. If it were me I'd prototype it with 1 or 2 panels, get everything working and then measure actual load as I intended to use it.  Then you can decide on the power supplies as makes sense for the real load.

128A at 5v is only 640w so you can run this off of a single electrical outlet. I agree with the recommendation to use multiple smaller power supplies, perhaps 15 or 20A each. It will avoid the need to use very thick copper cables and is somewhat less of a fire hazard.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful and detailed answer! Would you just recommend soldering them in parallel or just using a regular power strip?

Comment: @Jordan I don't think it matters.  I would do whatever makes sense for the application.